# Script for selective dissolving of multiple features

Tags: arcpy, modelbuilder, dissolve

I am kinda new to Python and arcpy and have done some basic online courses on this. So I do have an idea how these scripts are structured/written and how they work. Now I have to perform a seemingly complicated analysis for my master thesis which goes something like this:

I have an excel file in matrix form of around 400 polygon features (municipalities). Each municipality has a relationship with others around it (no. of people commuting daily between the municipalities). I have to somehow make a script/model which dissolves each municipality with only that municipality (out of 400) which has the highest no. of commuters travelling towards it (not from it). This might make one municipality dissolve with multiple municipalities also which is fine.

Anything like this has been done before? I'm thinking about the script and I can't think how I make this selective dissolve?

---

[image: The excel table.]

This is how the table looks like its not really a matrix but I guess it can be converted into one like in mentioned by Richard. The first two columns are origin and destination IDs and the last column is the no. of commuters.

Comment: You _should_ only get ~400 merged shapefiles, one for each municipality, at least based on your described process. That's still a lot, but not unmanageable.

Comment: You are right. I'm sorry I actually meant I'll get a lot of features in total (more than 400) because some features might be present in more than one merged shapefiles.

Comment: how is the relationship of commuters between municipalities defined? it seems to me that if this is a number given in an attribute column, could you run a loop to find the municipality with the highest number of commuters and run the merge tool based on that result?

Comment: I am unclear what attributes the merged shape should have.  Will it have the attributes of the two Cities combined somehow?  Will each shape have a destination ID and one or more origin IDs?  If you merge the origin/destination shapes into one shape you will have 400 shapes in the end, not more, unless you expect two or more cities to have the same number of commuters to a given city and do not merge the shapes.

Comment: @RichardFairhurst Yes you are correct the shapes will be 400 but there will be features that will be included in more than one shape.

Comment: @JasonBK What you are saying makes sense to me and I just realized these are 400 'features' in the same shapefile and not 400 shapefiles. So what I need is dissolve rather than merge. At the moment the relationship is defined in an excel table like a matrix showing commuters from each municipality to every other. I don't know how I can put this matrix in the attribute table and then make the script perform the selection and dissolve.

Comment: @jJasonBK Another longer way would be I think to select the maximum commuter municipality myself for each of the 400 municipalities and then put this one municipality in the table and then make a script to just perform the dissolve for each municipality in the table. But the first option seems much more useful (and quicker) if I share this script tool later for other people.

Comment: a screenshot of the matrix would be super helpful.

Comment: yes a screenshot would be helpful..perhaps if you don't necessarily need all the commuter totals in your mapped features, you could run a simple Excel formula to get the largest value in each row and make a new column with that value for each municipality? then add that column as an attribute.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way to set up the City Matrix in Excel so that you can get the Destination City row to report the Origin City with the maximum trip rate.

[image: Set Up In Excel to Find Max Origin City for Each Destination City]

The formula for column G is simply:

=Max(B3:F3) for cell G3 and copied down.

Column H is a number for the number of rows down from the current row to find the City name at the bottom.  In the case of a 400x400 matrix it would go from 401 to 2.

The formula for column I is only slightly more complex:

=HLOOKUP(G3,B3:F$8,H3,FALSE) for cell I3 and then copied down.

You would of course have to adjust the formula values to match your larger matrix set up.

Once you had your Cities listed, you could copy onto a new sheet just the Destination City Names and the associated Origin City Names using the Copy Values method to make it easier to import the essential spreadsheet for matching the shapes into ArcMap.

Comment: Thanks this is very helpful. But the problem is more about ArcMap I think. I only want to dissolve municipalities that are CONNECTED spatially. So I would only consider the maximum commuter flow from the connected municipalities. How do I see which municipalities are connected to each municipality? I can use the select by location tool but then I would have to do that 400 times.

Comment: I just found out that I have 55000 rows and I cannot make a matrix because I will then have 55000 columns whereas excel limit is 16384 columns only.

Comment: You said nothing about spatially connected municipalities as far as I saw.  In any case, the matrix for the set of spatially connected municipalities will now come from the Spatial Join tool.  You would join the layer to itself with the One to Many option and then eliminate the set of features where the city joined to itself.  Once you see the output of the Spatial Join tool you will already have all of the possible the origin/destination cities in the record set.  From there you can assign the commuters for each origin city and find the max in Excel or with Summary Statistics.

Comment: Once you have the set of origin/destination cities created by the Spatial Join tool they will have the pair of City IDs in the output of each feature created, just like your table.  You cannot directly join on two fields, but you can use the tool I created to create a single Case_ID field to represent the values of the field pair between your table above and the Spatial Join output.  See this thread for the Multiple Field Key to Single Field Key tool.  https://geonet.esri.com/message/517458#517458

Comment: The 55000 rows would not create a 55000x55000 matrix, because those rows do not represent the set of UNIQUE City names.  To convert it to a true matrix you would need to get the set of unique values in the first column to become the rows and the set of unique values in the second column to become columns.  So 55000 records is probably closer to a matrix of 235 unique cities (the square root of 55000).  But since the matrix transposition process would not be easy and you don't need a true matrix, just the result of the Spatial Join tool, you can use your table exactly like it is.

Comment: Thank you so much. Spatial join worked very well and I removed the overlapping joins. But the tool you suggested is not working. ArcMap gives this error and the tool does not open - Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 50, in getParameterInfo
AttributeError: 'Parameter' object has no attribute 'filters'.
And there is a little red cross on top of the script icon inside the toolbox in catalogue window.

Comment: You have to use the 10.2 version of the tool that is attached in a later post in the same thread.  The version you downloaded only works for 10.3 and higher.

Comment: I do not understand what is an input secondary table and why do I need it??

Comment: The tool requires two tables (or feature classes) and adds a field to both to match them up.  The Spatial Join is the primary table and the Excel table is the Secondary Table.  You have to import your spreadsheet into ArcMap using the Conversion tools Excel to Table tool.  You then have to match the field names for Origin City and Destination City in both sources.  The tool will add a CASE_ID field to both sources that will make a Single field join possible that represents both fields.  Then you can transfer the trip counts to your shapes, and do Summary Statistics on the shapes.

Comment: Summary Statistics would output the Destination City as the Case field and Max trip count for each city after the data transfer.  Then you could use my tool to match the Summary Statistics table as the Primary Table and Spatial Join output as the Secondary Table.  Match the field names for the Destination City and Max Traffic Count.  Any CASE_ID value in the Spatial Join that is positive will match the summary and be the top Count for that City.  This will give the Origin City ID that has that Max Count for each City.

Comment: Did everything exactly. In the end, I cannot see the traffic count field to select it in the field list for secondary table (spatial join output) in your tool. May be this is because that field was created using join and was not originally part of that table? Because I cannot see other fields that were joined as well like Origin and Destination fields from the excel table.

Comment: You must add a double field to the Spatial Join and transfer the counts directly to it by creating a normal join on the first CASE_ID and then using the Field Calculator to calculate the counts into the Spatial Join output.  That is what I meant by transfer the Counts.  So if you did not do that you did not do everything exactly.  I did not write the tool to recognize a join, only to read tables directly.  Adding user defined joins not set up by the tool (or additional joins set up by the tool) would add complexity to the interface that I personally would never use and won't support.

Comment: I cannot put every step in detail in my responses, because using comments to describe detailed step by step instructions does not work.  You should post on Esri's GeoNet if you want that level of instructions.  The responses there can be as long and as detailed as necessary without creating bogus "Answers".  The StackExchange set up is not designed for creating a lengthy and detailed back and forth set of responses.

Comment: Okay. Its done. Thanks alot for you input. Really appreciated.

Comment: To reinforce the comment by @RichardFairhurst above I recommend reviewing "[Stack Exchange is NOT a discussion forum](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92107/is-stack-overflow-a-forum)".  To better understand why we use a focussed Q&A format rather than be a discussion forum I recommend read the paragraph [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244534/were-working-on-a-new-stat-to-help-convey-the-reach-of-your-posts-here) on **You gotta get this to get us**.  When used as designed any semblance of being bogus should evaporate from the answers here.